# Element inside div should not interfere on the event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler

I have a **div** and inside it I have a **p**. The paragraph is visually above the div. My event handler is being affected by the paragraph.

This is my event handler:

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseover mouseleave", ".ct-symbol", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
});
```

So, when I am moving my mouse on the div, it will toggle the class if I cross the paragraph. What I want is to only toggle the class once I enter/leave the div. I also tried to use this:

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseover mouseleave", ".ct-symbol", ".ct-symbol p" function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
});
```

But now it toggles twice once I move my mouse above the paragraph...

Comment: Either check for the correct element in your function or stop event propagation using `event.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".ct-symbol", function() {
    if (this.id == "container-map")
    {
       $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
    }
});
```

That should work. It only fires when `this` has the same id as the div.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `mouseenter` not `mouseover`

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".ct-symbol" function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is that your **active-b** class is only affected when you leave/enter.

You need to use **mouseenter** not **mouseover**.

```
$("#container-map").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".ct-symbol", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-b");
});
```